# Error during archive: symbols referenced by indirect symbol table entries that can't be stripped

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have a project which compile and run fine (even when built using "build for archive" command).

However, when I want to Archive it (for MAS publishing), I get the following error:

> Command /Developer/usr/bin/strip failed with exit code 1
>   /Developer/usr/bin/strip: symbols referenced by indirect symbol table entries that can't be stripped in xxx

where xxx is a subproject of my project (framework).

What can be the issue? (I checked, everything is properly signed)

Answer (score 10):

[image]

In my case, changing **Strip Style** build setting from *All Symbols* to *Debugging Symbols* fixed the problem.

Comment: This must be the valid answer to the question I believe.

Answer (score 0):

strip has to do with the symbol stripping during archiving/building.  We will need slightly more error information to give you better help.

It sounds like the subproject may be having it's symbols stripped and shouldn't be.  Try opening the build settings for the sub-project and turn "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" off and see if that fixes it.

Comment: hmm, perhaps!  Hadn't thought of the distinction particularly.  If he turns off striping in his subproject build setting and that fixes it, then it will be the answer though, won't it? Maybe I should have phrased it better in my text above...

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your subProject's Target Membership in your project. Before building for Archive, Please build for normal mode. This is an easy way to check any linking errors.